# Beautiful Soup and Requests - add missing </td></tr> to one line of HTML code

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently Python coding using Beautiful Soup.  The website i am trying to extract data from is http://xml.coverpages.org/country3166.html

On the whole I can get everything working that I want.  I am extracting country code and country from the HTML using the <tr> tag.  This is for a project I am setting myself.

The problem is that the source HTML is missing some closing tags on one of the countries (Moldova).  See below.  This means when I loop through my code it stops doing what I need at Moldova.

```
<tr valign=top><td>MA</td><td>Morocco</td></tr>
<tr valign=top><td>MC</td><td>Monaco</td></tr>
<tr valign=top><td>MD</td><td>Moldova, Republic of
<tr valign=top><td>MG</td><td>Madagascar</td></tr>
```

Thanks

I know I could just create a new text file and manually amend it but is there anything I can do Beautiful Soup wise to fix this?  My plan was to iterate through each line until Moldova is found and then append </td></tr> on the end.  Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

If I inspect the source you've linked the HTML seems fine, there's probably a mistake in your way of scraping the data.

A small example were we search for each `tr`, get it's children (2x `td`), and parse those as `code` and `country` to show a list:

```py
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', 'http://xml.coverpages.org/country3166.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.findAll("tr"):
    childs = tr.findChildren();
    code = childs[0].getText();
    country = childs[1].getText();

    print(code, country)
```

Will output:

```
AD Andorra
AE United Arab Emirates
AF Afghanistan
AG Antigua & Barbuda
AI Anguilla
AL Albania
AM Armenia
AN Netherlands Antilles
AO Angola
AQ Antarctica
AR Argentina
AS American Samoa
... and many more, including Moldova and beyond
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will try it out later.  When i view the HTML in Chrome the </tr> and </td> for Moldova are missing.  Presumably your method works irrespective of this.